# Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with Apache

Tags: windows, apache, asp.net-core

I need to host my `.Net Core 2.1` application on `Windows` with `Apache`. Do you have any tutorials? I found many tutorials to host on `Linux` but none on `Windows`.

Comment: No... No... Apache is only on Linux server. For windows server, you can use IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache does not provide official package for windows but their are 3rd party  binary distributions available, some are:

1. XAMPP
2. Apache Lounge
3. Bitnami WAMP Stack
4. WampServer

You can see this Hosting article where [ASP.NET Core hosted on Apache on Windows with XAMPP](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-host-apache-windows/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot host a .NET Core application on Apache on Windows. What you can do is to use Kestrel with a reverse proxy such as describe in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy).

Comment: Yes. Even on Linux I need to use Kestrel with a reverse proxy. Do you have a tutorial how to configure the Apache on Windows to run ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @derodevil Apache on Windows cannot run an ASP.NET Core application, there is no module to do so. What you can do is to set your Apache up to be a reverse proxy working with Kestrel, such as described in the link.

Comment: @rudolfdobias probably because Apache gives you more configuration options such as hosting multiple domains in the same port which Kestrel doesn't support yet as of Oct 2019.

Comment: @derodevil do you find any way to host the asp.net core application on Windows? i have same issue